# Why 'Den' instead of 'Der' in this sentence? Den größten Fehler, den man im Leben machen kann

Tags: definite-article

> Den größten Fehler, den man im Leben machen kann, ist, immer Angst zu
>   haben, einen Fehler zu machen.

This is translated into

> The biggest mistake you can make in life is always being afraid of
>   making a mistake.

But, why is it "Den grössten Fehler"? Shouldn't it be "Der grössten Fehler"?
(Fehler is masculine noun and it seems to be a subject word.)

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage  ok, but to me, it seems Fehler is the subject word for the whole sentence and the verb of the whole sentence is 'ist'. The object of the first 'machen' is 'den'(a relative noun). Isn't it right?

Comment: It's falsely attributed to Dietrich Bonhoeffer, but actually from Elbert Hubbard (1901): "The greatest mistake you can make in life is to be continually fearing you will make one." It was then incorrectly translated into German. See this [article](http://falschzitate.blogspot.com/2019/04/den-groten-fehler-den-man-im-leben.html) by Gerald Krieghofer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.
This is a mistake.
It should be "*Der größte* Fehler, den man im Leben machen kann".

Comment: Oh, it's reassuring my understanding was correct! Thanks!